# How to reuse angular 2 routes?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a modularized angular 2 app, with sub-routes defined in each module, the main routing file is like follows:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'a', loadChildren: './src/a.module#AModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'b', loadChildren: './src/b.module#BModule'
    },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/a/1', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/a/1' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

The problem is, I have a component in A that needs to use a component in B, in AComponent I navigate to BComponent, I do what I have to do in B and back to AComponent, the problem is that my AComponent is recreated and all data filled in form is lost.

I tried to use the RouteReuseStrategy and not worked properly, in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VNAUwUMaiu3lXzPNKIe6) is the example with RouteReuseStrategy commented, to enable it just uncomment the code in app.ts.

Someone knows how can I navigate without losing data in previous route and not using ui-router?